# Node.js callback closure/scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, closure

- Is it a bad idea to use the `notfound` callback like this? If so, why not? (bad scope/closure? I'm a noob node.js dev.)
- Is it a bad idea to use the `saveCallback` callback like this? I have a feeling it's dangerous, but I don't want to declare `saveCallback` before `queryCallback` as save happens after query.

```
create: function(registerDetails, found, notfound) {

    var query = db.User
        .findOne({ username: registerDetails.username });

    var queryCallback = function(err, user) {
        if (user != null) found(user);
        else {
            var newUser = new db.User();
            newUser.username = registerDetails.username;
            newUser.password = registerDetails.password;
            newUser.save(saveCallback);
        }
    };

    var saveCallback = function(err, user) {
        notfound(user);
    };

    query.exec(queryCallback);
},
```

What's a more elegant way of writing this so that

```
// 1) don't nest like crazy.
.exec(function(){
    if () {
        newUser.save(function(){
            notfound(); // really? because we know node.js will ever chain 2 callbacks max. </sarcasm>
        }
    }

// 2) don't make people read "down and back up"
var saveCallback = function() {
    // Dejavu... I've been here before...
};
var queryCallback = function() {
    saveCallback(); // Back from last line, ohhhhh this is what saveCallback used for. Go back up.
};
query.exec(queryCallback); // Ohhhhh so that's what it's used for. Now go back up and read what it does.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question,

I would go with this:

```
create: function (registerDetails, found, notfound) {

    db.User.findOne({
        username: registerDetails.username
    }).exec(queryCallback);

    function queryCallback(err, user) {
        if (user != null) {
            found(user);
        } else {
            var newUser = new db.User();
            newUser.username = registerDetails.username;
            newUser.password = registerDetails.password;
            newUser.save(saveCallback);
        }
    };

    function saveCallback(err, user) {
        notfound(user);
    };
},
```

Basically, I

- Used the fact that JavaScript does [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), you can use functions prior to having them declared. Given this I put the `.exec()` on top, I also did away with `query` which I would have called `userQuery`.
- I put proper braces and newlines around `if( user!= null )`, to be tested, but if you can get away with it, you should consider `if(user)`
- I moved from `var xx = function()` to `function xx()` because anonymous functions in stacktraces are not fun

Comment: Let me read through about hoisting first. Much thanks for the input. It's interesting because that's the exact reason I put the query.exec at the end. If it's a standard practice doing then there's no harm putting it at top.

Comment: You know what. I'm marking this an answer. From your link "The reason scoping is so confusing in JavaScript is because it looks like a C-family language." <- exactly what I was looking for. I am a C# developer, and I find JS scope confusing to say the least.

Comment: You could get rid of the `else` by doing `if ( user ) return found(user);` But typically your errors are handled first, so I would do `if (!user) return saveNewUser(user);` then just drop into the `found(user)` below that.